# "Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock" while adjusting ext4 filesystem with tune2fs

Tags: ubuntu

I've a shiny new Ubuntu 11.04 installation.
In addition to the system disk, I've added a 2TB drive (/dev/sda) for data.

System monitor reports 1419.5 GiB "Free" and 1326.3 "Available".

Reading around the web leads me to believe that the system is reserving this ~6% as "[root reserved space](http://ubuntuhowtos.com/howtos/tune2fs_increase_available_space)"

Well, I don't think I want "root reserved space" on a pure data disk, so I tried the oft suggested:

```
tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda
```

on the drive only to receive:

```
tune2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock
```

The filesystem is ext4 and the partitioning is somehow "GUID" (<- Not familiar with this one)

The mighty Google was little help.  Can anyone out there tell me how to eliminate the "reserved space" on this new data drive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be accessing `/dev/sda1`, not `/dev/sda`.

`/dev/sda` is the entire disk. Partitions on the disk are assigned numbers, e.g. `/dev/sda1`. With limited exceptions (e.g. SD cards), individual partitions, not entire disks, are formatted with filesystems.

If the filesystem is somehow on the whole disk, you'll want to repartition the disk using `fdisk` or a similar utility so that there's at least one partition. You can then format `/dev/sda1` as ext4. This operation will erase all data on the disk, so be sure to back up anything important before you proceed.

For NVMe SSDs, you'll typically use `/dev/nvme0n1` for the disk (NVMe device 0, namespace 1<sup>1</sup>), and partitions are designated `p1`, `p2`, etc., as in `/dev/nvme0n1p1`. If you have more than one NVMe SSD, the additional disks will probably be named `/dev/nvme1n1`, `/dev/nvme2n1`, and so on, with the same `p1`/`p2`/etc. suffixes for partitions.

---

<sup>1</sup>NVMe allows devices to have multiple *namespaces*. These allow a single drive to be treated as multiple devices, even though they may physically use the same connection. Multiple namespaces are almost never seen outside of enterprise/datacenter SSDs, so you should never need to deal with devices like `/dev/nvme2n3p1` (device 2, namespace 3, partition 1).